# view app timeline is going to personal timeline

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I am trying to add an application as a tab to a Facebook fan page and when I click "View App Timeline" in order to then select "add to my page" I am being sent back to my personal timeline. Is anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To add an page tab, just enter the URL

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL1`

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/